# One to many - many to one relationship in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have this Coupon Class

```
package Kinn.College.CouponManagementSystem.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table (name = "companies")
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy =  GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "company_id")
    private int id; // id of the company
    @Column (name = "company_name")
    private String name; // name of the company
    @Column (name = "company_email")
    private String email; // email of the company
    @Column (name = "company_password")
    private String password; // password of the company

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company_id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Coupon> coupons;


}
```

and I have this company class

```
package Kinn.College.CouponManagementSystem.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table (name = "companies")
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy =  GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "company_id")
    private int id; // id of the company
    @Column (name = "company_name")
    private String name; // name of the company
    @Column (name = "company_email")
    private String email; // email of the company
    @Column (name = "company_password")
    private String password; // password of the company

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company_id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Coupon> coupons;


}
```

for some reason, the one to many - many to one relationship creates an error when I try to get a company from the DB with a list of coupons.

I'm using this syntax to get a copmany from DB.

```
{
Company company = companyService.getCompanyById(1);
        System.out.println("Got company by id: " + company);
}
```

if I'm removing the list of coupons from every company, it works just fine.
This is the error message;

```
2023-01-16T11:59:33.266+02:00 ERROR 16808 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Collection 'Kinn.College.CouponManagementSystem.entities.Company.coupons' is 'mappedBy' a property named 'company_id' which does not exist in the target entity 'Kinn.College.CouponManagementSystem.entities.Coupon'
```

I've tried asking multiple people know Spring very well and all of them say it looks okay, that it should work.

Comment: You share two times the same class

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that a company can relate to many coupons.

So in **Coupon** class, you can have a Company member which represents the company it belongs to :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
private Company company;
```

Here, company_id would become the foreign key that points to primary key of company table

And in **Company** class, you can have List of coupons that it owns:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Coupon> coupons = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

`mapped_by` reference the property or the referenced class, not the column name:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Coupon> coupons;
```

BTW: Take care of java naming conventions. Package names should only contains lower case character

Answer (score 0):

The `Company` entity should have a field to point to all its coupons as shown below:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="company")
private Set<Coupon> coupons;
```

The `mappedBy` field is the instance variable name we'll use in `Coupon` entity to point to the associated `Company`.

The `Coupon` entity should have a field to point to all its coupons like:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="company_id", nullable=false)
private Company company;
```

The name field refers to the name of the foreign key in the `Coupon` table that points to the `Company` table.

You can check this article https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many.